# Rails Calling an image from an article which is uploaded in the article via shrine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, shrine

Hey Guys i want to create a box on my home where my most recent article is displayed, in the box there should be the title and a few lines of content of the post (which is pretty doable i guess) but i also  want to have the image which is in the post uploaded via shrine and trix. 
In general i dont know how to get the images from the posts to use them. I know that could be difficult if there would be more images but then i would like to randomize them.

My model post.rb

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  validates :title, :content, :presence => true
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged
end
```

my model image.rb

```
class Image < ApplicationRecord
# adds an `image` virtual attribute
include ::PhotoUploader::Attachment.new(:image)

end
```

my image controller

```
class ImagesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def create
    image_params[:image].open if image_params[:image].tempfile.closed?

    @image = Image.new(image_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @image.save
        format.json { render json: { url: @image.image_url }, status: :ok }
      else
        format.json { render json: @image.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def image_params
    params.require(:image).permit(:image)
  end
```

end

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate a signature to handle multiple files. With shrine it would look like this:

```
# db/migrations/001_create_photos.rb
create_table :images do |t|
  t.integer :imageable_id
  t.string  :imageable_type
  t.text    :image_data
  t.text    :image_signature
end
add_index :images, :image_signature, unique: true

# app/uploaders/image_uploader.rb
class ImageUploader < Shrine
  plugin :signature
  plugin :add_metadata
  plugin :metadata_attributes :md5 => :signature

  add_metadata(:md5) { |io| calculate_signature(io) }
end

# app/models/image.rb
class Image < ApplicationRecord
  include ImageUploader::Attachment.new(:image)
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true

  validates_uniqueness_of :image_signature
end
```

Also for consistencies sake in your code either call it image or photo. Your uploader is called Photos but everywhere else it is called Image.

The last change you need is in your controller for it to accept an array of images instead of one image. To do that you need to simply use an array:

```
def show
  @image = Image.order('RANDOM()').limit(1).first
end

private
def images_params
  params.require(:images).permit(images: [)
end
```

Comment: do i need to add those aswell " t.integer :imageable_id t.string  :imageable_type " or do i just have to run add_index :images, :image_signature, unique true ?

Comment: Without seeing your schema I am not sure, but I would assume you don’t have these columns in your db.